# Тип url вместо пробела "%20" или "+"

Tags: javascript

В гугле и на некоторых сайтах вместо пробела стоит "+", но например в js encodeURI делает вместо пробела "%20". Как можно сделать "+" в js??

Comment: Извините за неуместный (дурацкий) вопрос. 

А вместо + на этих сайтах в URL надо использовать %2b ?

Comment: Нет мне надо было наоборот, и как это сделать мне уже помогли

Comment: Вы не поняли. Я сам для себя заинтересовался. 

Если пробел заменять в URL на "+", то что писать в том же URL вместо плюса ? Hex код символа "+" 2b. Т.е. надо "%2b" ?

Кто знает ?

Comment: В этом случае да %2B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кстати, в JS есть ещё и [encodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent).

Я обычно себе расширяю строкововый класс своим методом примерно так:

```
String.prototype.escapeURI = function () {
    return encodeURIComponent(this).replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
//...
encoded_param = "foo bar".escapeURI(); // => foo+bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Где то так:

```
if(location.href.match(/%20/ig))
{
    location.href = encodeURI(location.href.replace(/%20/ig, '+'));
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```